# What's wrong with my code? (coderbyte capitalize letters)

Tags: javascript

I am trying a coderbyte challenge and in repl.it my code works. In jsfiddle, using JSHint, it says everything looks great.

Yet, when I test the parameters on the coderbyte site, it says "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list". I don't understand why I get an error there but not on the other sites? I've been looking at this for about an hour and don't know how else to look at it.

If you have any advice, I really appreciate it. Thanks for reading.

```
function LetterCapitalize(str) { 
   var phrase = str.split(""), i = -1, a = 0;

   for (i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
     if (i === 0) {
        phrase[i] = phrase[i].toUpperCase();
     }
     else if (phrase[i] === " ") {
        phrase[i + 1] = phrase[i + 1].toUpperCase();
     }
   }
  a = phrase.join(" ");
  console.log(a);
}

LetterCapitalize("hello world");
```

Comment: Looks fine, not sure how we can help you with a working example.

Comment: Check the notes on how text is input into your function - if I remember correctly Coderbyte runs javascript in Node.js ?

Comment: Damn, thanks for taking a look. I guess I can ask the people at coderbyte what the problem is. =/ I know I could probably find snippets of someone's code and mash it together to pass their test doing this another way but every time I am able to complete one of these with my own code I want to enter my own answer. Hopefully this will be resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Jhecht I'll look into that now.

Comment: I just pasted your answer in coderbyte's challenge, and it worked fine (had to replace logging with a return, of course). Btw. there's one more thing you need to fix for the challenge, but the syntax is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I see a bug in your code, although not a syntax error. `phrase[i + 1]` will crash if `str` *ends* with a *space*. In that scenario, you are on the last character, found a space, and are trying to access the last character + 1, which is impossible.

I can at least verify my code works. Try this:

```js
function letterCapitalize(str) {
    var phrase = str.split('');
    
    for (i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            phrase[i] = phrase[i].toUpperCase();
        }
        else if (phrase[i] == ' ') {
            if (i + 1 < phrase.length) phrase[i + 1] = phrase[i + 1].toUpperCase();
        }
    }
    
    return phrase.join('');
}


alert(letterCapitalize("hello world"));
```

Comment: Thanks for this, that did not occur to me. Unfortunately, when I paste your code into coderbyte I still get the same issue I do above. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Nevermind, sorry everyone! I'm an idiot and didn't put quotations around the parameter in coder byte, which it gives examples for. Thank you all for your help, much appreciated!